# Intellij change build.gradle file permanently

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I would like to make a permanent change in build.gradle in Intellij. Every time I create a new projet, I have to add a few line (repository, dependencies).

Is there a "template" for  the default build.gradle file that I could change?